# Weird issue where a local variable isn't resetting to 0 in c++

Tags: c++

So I was doing a super simple program of counting the amount of characters in a character array, and the return value I'm getting really isn't making any sense...

This is the function:

```
    int countLetters(const char s[])
    {
    int count = 0;
    while(s[count] != '\0')
        {
        count = count + 1;
        }
    return count;
    }
```

And my main function has this:

```
    const char ch[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
    const char cha[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    const char chacha[1] = {'a'};
    cout << countLetters(ch);
    cout << countLetters(cha);
    cout << countLetters(chacha);
```

The expected output should be 5 5 1 but instead I'm getting 8 13 14 and I really have no clue why...count is a local variable so it shouldn't be saving the value, it even gets reset to 0 at the start of every function call, and it still works properly. Is there some syntax issue going on, or is there something wrong with my compiler? I really can't figure out what the issue is...

Comment: Which one of the values in those arrays is equal to `\0`?

Comment: @juanchopanza doesn't c++ assign that to the very last value in a char array? Or is the issue the arrays get stored sequentially in memory, that section keeps growing and the null terminator keeps going further and further down?

Comment: `"hello"` would be null terminated. `{'h','e','l','l','o'}` is not null terminated.

Comment: @Varri The former. C++ doesn't add elements to arrays.

Comment: @Varri - all you have to do is LOOK!!!  Fire up a debugger, and examine your array.  Or step through your code.  Or heck - generate assembly output and look at that!  But NEVER ASSUME!.  Always LOOK!

Comment: @paulsm4 I just had the understanding that c++ would put '\0' after every char array no matter how you stored the characters in it. That's why I didn't think that it was something as simple as changing char ch[] = {'a'} to char ch[] = "a";.

Comment: Right, which was an _assumption_ you did not verify. Therefore, this problem arose. Please, verify your assumptions. It will save us time as well as you! A good skill to learn. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
  const char ch[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

is not null-terminated. This:

```
  const char ch[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o', 0 };
```

would be. What you are seeing is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Exactly. Strings are automatically 0-terminated, but arrays aren't.

Comment: But the fact that OP is getting an output is somewhat surprising, why the while loop terminates if there isn't no null character in the array?

Comment: @svasa It;s undefined behaviour - anything could happen, and it's a waste of time to reason about it.

Comment: @svasa Somewhere beyond the range of the arrays there happens to be a byte full of zero. But formally it is undefined behaviour. A compiler could detect that the code is broken, and generate code to do anything it wants.

Comment: @svasa any random memory location has a 1 in 256 chance of being zero. More, since memory contents aren't random and zero has a higher chance of appearing - padding between variables is likely to be zero filled for instance.

Comment: This was a misunderstanding on my end then. I always thought c++ added a null terminator at the end of char arrays as well as strings. Thank you!

Comment: @Varri It should be pointed out that a *string constant* `"hello"` *will* be null-terminated. It's only arrays that aren't.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yup, that's where I had the misunderstanding. I didn't realize you could just do char ch[] = "whatever"; and that would work. I just had always thought c++ would put a null terminator from the way I originally had the arrays. I'm still fairly new to the language.